# How to always install fresh package version from repository

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, npm-install

I have private package located in private repository that used as dependency in other project. I installed it as recommended with

```
npm i --save git+https://github.com/company/project.git
```

I supposed that every time we run build on CI server it'll have fresh version from repository. But it doesn't work.

I tried to bump package version but this didn't help too.

The single way that works for me is to tag versions and install by tags, like this

`npm i --save git+https://github.com/company/project.git#v1`

which means for every package I have to update main project code with new version.

Maybe I don't understand some concepts behind NPM. So is it possibly to always get fresh version of package installed from repo?

Comment: npm requires a package.json file which has a version number value in it used for version control. Did you do run npm init on the git directory to create the .json file?

Comment: yes, I have. I bumped patch version of package but it didn't help